# Hard disk stop working after some time

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, power-supply

OK, this is a problem I am experiencing from the last few days. My PC starts normally, but many times when I work, my HD stops working and the PC get hangs. If I wait for few minutes (5-10 min), then the HD again start working and the PC began responding. I think the problem is with HD because when PC get hang the light of the HD stop flashing. I also have lots of power fluctuation in my house. So, Is this a problem with my HD or my Windows installation is corrupted.

Comment: That doesn't prove it's a HDD problem. It just proves that nothing uses HDD when it happens.

Comment: @gronostaj I am confused, that's why I am asking. Is this due to a corrupted windows installation

Comment: I don't know what causes the problem, I just wanted to let you know that HDD isn't the certain source of it. I've seen exactly the same issue mentioned od SU many times, maybe some of the older questions has been answered.

Comment: Cause and effect are confusing here. It could be that your PC hangs because of some software conflict, and then the HD stops working as well. The software conflict would not be a real lock but like two programs consuming all resources. On the other hand, because it restarts and you have power problems, I'd look in power management (the PC settings and your house). First thing I'd try is see if you can do something about the fluctuations - get a UPS.

Comment: Please check the Event logs.

Comment: It's not unusual for Windows, after booting, to lock up for sometimes several minutes as it does whatever mysterious stuff it feels it must do.  Usually the drive is being used for most of this, but there are periods when no drive activity is noted.  (This is why people tend to leave Windows running, vs powering down when not in use.)

Comment: @Daniel, if you have that issue, startup programs are fighting over resources. Install Startup Delayer to delay the start of some of them (there's many programs you don't need right after startup).

Comment: Ok, I forget to tell. In my case low voltages are real culprit. Before, the last few days my voltage stabilizer is not working. So, the voltage are very low. Now, the problem is over and my PC is working smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows...verify you don't have configured the hard drive to turn off: Control Panel>power options>advanced power settings>Hard disk.

Answer (score -1):

If the HDD restarts when you try to access some data from it (using Windows Explorer) then you have to apply a longer time of the setting Control Panel> Power options> Advanced power settings> Hard disk. For instance put there 600 mins or 6000 mins (!)